# Direct printing Crystal Report to Printer, instead of asking for print dialog(report viewer)

Tags: printing, crystal-reports, report, bulk

I am working on a windows application, where i need to give bulk printing feature. Here i have
a format to print a document, and i need to print multiple document at one click. I am using Crystal Reports, but every time it goes to report viewer and we need to give print from them.

Is there any way so that i can directly print all the documents from database at once on single click button, If its not possible in Crystal Reports could you suggest any other way.???????

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the printtoprinter() method at run time?  You can hide the default print button, add a custom print button that will make a call this method.